# Remove Empty option from Gender drodopwn and make female default option

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, magento1.9.3

I have added dropdown to choose `Gender` on Register-page.
There are only two options ie `Male` and `Female` in Backend.
On Frontend, In Gender dropdown, first value display as `Blank` then `Male` and then `Female`.

I want to Remove that blank option and `female` Option as default.
If user not select any option from dropdown then it should be considered as `Female`.

[image: Gender Dropdown On Register page]

```
<label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('gender')?>" class="gender-
  label <?php if ($this->isRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>"><?
  php if ($this->isRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this-
  >__('Gender') ?>
</label>


<div class="input-box">
      <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('gender')?>" name="<?php 
        echo $this->getFieldName('gender')?>" title="<?php echo 
        Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Gender')) ?>"<?php if 
        ($this->isRequired()):?> class="validate-select"<?php endif; ?> <?
        php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
         <?php $options = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')-
           >getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getAllOptions();?>
              <?php $value = $this->getGender();?>
                 <?php foreach ($options as $option):?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php 
                       if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' 
                       selected="selected"' ?>><?php echo $option['label'] 
                    ?></option>
                 <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Update your phtml

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove first (empty) option and set value as *Female* (2) when there is no selected value:

```
<label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('gender') ?>" class="gender-label <?php if ($this->isRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>">
    <?php if ($this->isRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('Gender') ?>
</label>


<div class="input-box">
    <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('gender') ?>" name="<?php
    echo $this->getFieldName('gender') ?>" title="<?php echo
    Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Gender')) ?>"
        <?php if ($this->isRequired()): ?> class="validate-select"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
        <?php
        $options = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        unset($options[0]);
        $value = $this->getGender() ? $this->getGender() : '2'; // 2 for female
        foreach ($options as $option): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php
            if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' 
                       selected="selected"' ?>><?php echo $option['label']
                ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code

```
<?php $options = Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getAllOptions();?>
```

with

```
<?php $options = array_reverse(Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->getAttribute('gender')->getSource()->getAllOptions(false));?>
```